# including javascript function in .module file in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

on click of button i want hi message to be displayed using javascript in drupal.I have made a .js file and know that to incude that i must use  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'document') .'/click.js'); but the problem is to create button i used  $form['click'] = array(
 '#type' => 'button',
 '#attributes' => array('onclick' =>drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'document') . '/cancel.js')),
 '#value' => t('click'),
  );

I want that hi message which i have included in js file to be shown when button is clicked.
Please help

---

Hi thanx for your concern..........
here is the way i proceeded in .module file

function document_form(&$node) {
 $form['click'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#attributes' => array('onclick' =>message()),
    '#value' => t('click'),
  );
  }

function document_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'document').'/cancel.js', 'module');
    $settings['click'] = array(
        'nid' => $form['nid']['#value'],
        'cid' => $form['cid']['#value'],
        'uid' => $form['uid']['#value'],
        'pid' => $form['pid']['#value'],
      );
      drupal_add_js($settings, 'setting');
}

and my .js file code is as follows:

function message()
        {
            alert("This alert box was called");
        }

```
<body>
</body>
```

but still onclick of button i m not getting the message "This alert box was called"
Kindly help where the problem is coming now.......
Thanx in advance....
in wait of your response

Answer (score 0):

The form alter won't add the JS file in the way you are wanting.

In the function you create the form you can use drupal_add_js, outside of the creation of the form array.

Then you can use the onclick to call the function in your JS file.

A better way to do this is to use drupal behaviours to add an click listner to the button (see example [here](http://www.nicklewis.org/drupal-hackers-cookbook/jquery-js/unlocking-drupal-behavior)).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like simplest solution would be, as you actually don't need the button to go to submit and other form stuff.

1. add a link to the text
2. style the the link as button using css .mybuttons{}
3. hook the js on the id. $(#mybutton1).alert..